# What is the difference in nuance between 지루한 건 and 지루한 걸?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference in nuance between 지루한 건 and 지루한 걸 in this case?
Why is 지루한 건 better in this case?

> 부탁이 하나 있는데요. 제가 한국어로 한 얘기에 좀 대답해 주실 수 있어요?  고쳐주시는 건 감사한데 저한테는 제 문자의
>   내용이 더 중요하거든요.  대부분 **(지루한 건/지루한 걸)** 잘 알겠는데 첨삭만 받으면 좀 서운해져요

Comment: 건 = 것은, 걸 = 것을. In this case you are trying to emphasize that "I know that it is boring", so using 은 to stress it would be more natural than just using 을.

Answer (score 1):

고쳐 주시는 건 (고쳐주시는 건) and 지루한 건 are correct.

The last two sentences **imply** (or indirectly say) that the speaker ***cannot* accept something** because it is bad, wrong, or disappointing; the speaker is making *implicit comparisons/contrasts*. For such implication, no one will use 고쳐 주시는 걸 or 고쳐 주시는 것이 and 지루한 걸 instead; the **markers for comparison are 은 and 는**. As you well know, 건 is the shortened form of 것**은**.

고쳐 주시는 **건 감사한데** is expressing both the speaker's **gratefulness** for the listener's correction and the speaker's **dissatisfaction** about something (else); 대부분 지루한 **건 알겠는데** is expressing the speaker's **acknowledgment** of the boring contents and **unacceptability** of something else at the same time. Their following clauses are explaining the speaker's **dissatisfaction** and **unacceptability** rather than directly mentioning the speaker's wish.